# Removing rows in a nested struct in a spark dataframe using PySpark (details in text)

Tags: python, filter, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, nested

I am using pyspark and I have a dataframe object `df` and this is what the output of `df.printSchema()` looks like

```
root
 |-- M_MRN: string (nullable = true)
 |-- measurements: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- Observation_ID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Observation_Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Observation_Result: string (nullable = true)
```

I would like to filter out all the arrays in 'measurements' where the Observation_ID is not '5' or '10'. So currently when I run `df.select('measurements').take(2)` I get

```
[Row(measurements=[Row(Observation_ID='5', Observation_Name='ABC', Observation_Result='108/72'),
                   Row(Observation_ID='11', Observation_Name='ABC', Observation_Result='70'),
                   Row(Observation_ID='10', Observation_Name='ABC', Observation_Result='73.029'),
                   Row(Observation_ID='14', Observation_Name='XYZ', Observation_Result='23.1')]),
 Row(measurements=[Row(Observation_ID='2', Observation_Name='ZZZ', Observation_Result='3/4'),
                   Row(Observation_ID='5', Observation_Name='ABC', Observation_Result='7')])]
```

I would like that after I do the above filtering and run `df.select('measurements').take(2)` I get

```
[Row(measurements=[Row(Observation_ID='5', Observation_Name='ABC', Observation_Result='108/72'),
                   Row(Observation_ID='10', Observation_Name='ABC', Observation_Result='73.029')]),
 Row(measurements=[Row(Observation_ID='5', Observation_Name='ABC', Observation_Result='7')])]
```

Is there a way to do this in pyspark? Thank you in anticipation for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Spark 2.4, you can use Higher Order Function `FILTER` to filter out elements from an array. So if you want to remove elements where `Observation_ID` is not 5 or 10, you can do it as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn('measurements', expr("FILTER(measurements, x -> x.Observation_ID = 5 OR x.Observation_ID = 10)"))
```

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I was looking for! A slightly more general version is replacing `x -> x.Observation_ID = 5 OR x.Observation_ID = 10` with `x -> x.Observation_ID in (5,10)`